# Setting up connection between 2 oracle instances for replication

Tags: oracle, database-replication

Hi everyone i have problem with setting up connection between two oracle instances for replication. I can connect via `sqlplus` using string like `

```
SQL> connect root/12345@orcl1
```

but I can't create query:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK remotedb
CONNECT TO root IDENTIFIED BY 12345
USING 'orcl1';
```

Also I can't set up it with Oracle database control. The error that I get is username or password of remote master isn't correct.

Comment: what *exact* error message do you get (i.e what is teh ORA-*nnnnn* number)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't suppose by any chance that the user "root" is a SYSDBA account on remote DB? If so, you cannot do this. Database links are not allowed to connect to SYSDBA accounts. The link will be created but you will get ORA-01017: invalid username/password.

Comment: I Granted to root all privileges, but didn't add him to any groop.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by enclosing password in double quotes